# Making a image disappear on collision

Tags: java, image, boolean

I am making a game where my character walks over images of coins. What I want to happen is that when he passes over the coins they disappear. I have researched and understand that it is possible to do this with boolean expressions but I am not sure on how to construct the statements. I would appreciate an explanation on how i would go about doing this and perhaps an example. Thank you

This is how i have displayed the coins and the character "Hood":

```
g.drawImage(coin1, cx1, cy1, this);                                  
int heightd = coin1.getHeight(this);
int widthd = coin1.getWidth(this); 

g.drawImage(coin2, cx2, cy2, this);                                  
int heighte = coin1.getHeight(this);
int widthe = coin1.getWidth(this); 

g.drawImage(coin3, cx3, cy3, this);                                  
int heightf = coin1.getHeight(this);
int widthf = coin1.getWidth(this); 

g.drawImage(coin4, cx4, cy4, this);                                  
int heightg = coin1.getHeight(this);
int widthg = coin1.getWidth(this); 


g.drawImage(Hood,hx , hy,this);                
int width = Hood.getWidth(this);
int height = Hood.getHeight(this);
```

Comment: how do you draw the background?

Comment: `it is possible to do this with boolean expressions`!!! well you can do it with `for` loops and other general (meaning unclear) statements also but either of them provide any real information.

Comment: @MartinFrank I am drawing the background the same way as the coins

Answer (score 1):

if you draw the background the same way as you draw your coins...

you can simply redraw the whole scenery **WITHOUT** the certain coin...

```
boolean drawCoin1 = true; //change this, maybe programatically
boolean drawCoin2 = true; //like:
boolean drawCoin3 = true; // boolean drawCoin3 = calculateCoinState();
boolean drawCoin4 = true; //

if(drawCoin1){
    g.drawImage(coin1, cx1, cy1, this);                                  
    int heightd = coin1.getHeight(this);
    int widthd = coin1.getWidth(this); 
}

if(drawCoin2){
    g.drawImage(coin2, cx2, cy2, this);                                  
    int heighte = coin1.getHeight(this);
    int widthe = coin1.getWidth(this); 
}

if(drawCoin3){
    g.drawImage(coin3, cx3, cy3, this);                                  
    int heightf = coin1.getHeight(this);
    int widthf = coin1.getWidth(this); 
}

if(drawCoin4){
    g.drawImage(coin4, cx4, cy4, this);                                  
    int heightg = coin1.getHeight(this);
    int widthg = coin1.getWidth(this); 
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. I shall do that then.

Comment: Also if I wanted to do this with boolean expressions how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Obviously you need to check if the bounding box of your `Hood` intersect with any of the coin's bounding boxes and then set the corresponding `drawCoinX` to `false`. This is the use of boolean expressions you need

Comment: as mentioned in my comment `boolean drawCoin3 = calculateCoinState();`

Comment: honsetly it's not soooo clear for me what the exact question would be, so maybe more information will be provided further ^^  (no offense)